# method in actionURL not being called

Tags: java, liferay

I have defined a jsp in which the following code is there:-

```
<portlet:actionURL name="checkOtp" var="otpDemo"></portlet:actionURL>
<form method="post" action="<%= otpDemo %>">
Enter otp:
<input type="text" name="otpText"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

When I submit the form I am getting Error as : `Render response is null because this tag is not being called within the context of a portlet`
 How to get rid of this error.Please help..Thanx in advance.

Comment: Have you created portlet action method with name `checkOtp`? Can you share that code as well?

Answer (score 1):

As, I assume that you are passing `RenderRequest` and `RenderResponse` objects to that action method, while these objects should be of `ActionRequest` and `ActionResponse` type.

If yes, for given `<portlet:actionURL name="checkOtp" var="otpDemo"></portlet:actionURL>`, your `actionListener` method in portlet's action class will be:

```
public void checkOtp(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse)
    throws IOException, PortletException {
        // your logic goes here
}
```

Comment: @Abhishek Jain, did this help you?